# "ago" used with a past tense

Tags: time, reported-speech, time-reference

> Alice: "I moved to Rome four years ago."
>
> Last year, Alice said she had moved to Rome **[...]**
>
> Alice: "I moved to Rome long ago."
>
> Last year, Alice said she had moved to Rome **[...]**

Would this be a correct way to finish these two sentences? I understand that "ago" means "before the *present* time", so is it acceptable to use it to mean "before the indicated *past* time"?

> Last year, Alice said she had moved to Rome **four years ago**
>
> Last year, Alice said she had moved to Rome **long ago**

Comment: Nowadays, ***ago*** almost always means *earlier than / before **now*** (time of *speaking*, not *before some contextually relevant time in the past*). So *Last Christmas she moved to Rome, which she had visited **four years ago*** would always imply she moved there ***three*** years after visiting, not four (since she moved there ***one year ago***).

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you should change "ago" to "before" or "earlier" in reported speech:

> Last year, Alice said she had moved to Rome four years *earlier*
>
> Last year, Alice said she had moved to Rome long *before*

See more examples [here](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/changing-time-and-place-references).

However, it seems to me that this rule is often not followed in casual speech. Keeping "ago" sounds quite natural English to me.

Another discussion on this topic can be found here: [Reported speech of (three years ago/ next week)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/38911/27840).