# Which tense is correct? “The teacher explained to us what dyslexia IS” or “what dyslexia was”

Tags: tense-agreement

This sentence:

> The teacher explained to us what dyslexia is.

I think this is correct, but other say that it should be:
The teacher explained to us what dyslexia was.

Since dyslexia still exists, I think it's okay to use present tense for the second part of the sentence, and it sounds better. Is that correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backshifting in reported speech - "I wanted to let you know that he HAS/HAD sent you the letter"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38886/backshifting-in-reported-speech-i-wanted-to-let-you-know-that-he-has-had-sent)

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct
 **The teacher explained to us what dyslexia is** 
 and **The teacher explained to us what dyslexia was** mean the same though some purists say that the first form is correct.
Even the universal truths can be in the past tense too.

I have seen the following examples in Raymond Murphy and Michael Swan's grammar books.

1 The teacher said that the earth moves round the sun

2 The teacher said that the earth moved round the sun

The second does not mean that the earth moved in the past but does not move now

Comment: Your examples are a different scenario in that the Earth moving around the sun *is* a current action and also *was* a past action that happened. Dyslexia *is still* dyslexia, so "what dyslexia *is*" is correct.

Comment: what dylexia was [to the people who were affected by it]. Both can be right. No doubt about it.

Comment: The answer is correct. Both tenses are idiomatic and optional. If **a stranger told me where the shop was to be found**, it's not to say that the shop is no longer located there.          https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249667/present-past-tense-in-a-subordinate-clause

Comment: Your answer contains multiple punctuation errors.  To strengthen your answer please observe proper formatting and punctuation.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Your comments and answer are helpful.