# Grammatical Correction

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> What he has said is right.

To me it is perfectly alright. But my mentor was telling like no it is grammatically incorrect. May I please know why it is grammatically wrong and what is the problem here in saying like this..

Comment: Mentor did not give a reason as to why they said it is incorrect?

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about it—assuming that what was right still *is* right. Backshifting is optional in the case of either a generalized or still-true statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backshifting in reported speech - "I wanted to let you know that he HAS/HAD sent you the letter"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38886/backshifting-in-reported-speech-i-wanted-to-let-you-know-that-he-has-had-sent)